# beginner: Memory usage on a stock install

Tags: keystonejs

When running a stock standard keystone install (via generator-keystone), its memory usage seems to be between 200-500mb. This is actually enough to crash the process on a new 512mb digitalocean vps I have created specifically to test whether this only happens in my local env.

The memory usage goes up when hitting any URL. So if I go to the Keystone Admin panel and go from collection to collection, go to the actual site, back to admin, after about 20 urls RAM usage is very high. If the process starts at 130mb, hitting 5-10 urls can see it rise to 250-300mb, and it won't stop there, never recovering down to 130mb again. Once again I have not edited any project files, this is a stock keystone install.

Help, what am I doing wrong? Is this normal? My plan to shift from hosting many small low-traffic sites in PHP on a single machine seems to be stuck in its tracks. Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding here? Maybe node is not for me? I stand to benefit from npm and keeping js both in front and back, so it appealed to me greatly.

ps. I have set 'session store' to mongo and installed the appropriate package, and set NODE_ENV to production, and issue persists.

pps. node version 0.12 installed via nvm, and this happens regardless of running this from supervisor or node.

Comment: By downgrading to node 0.10.36 it seems to be using less memory. That said, it still can get above 200mb usage on stock install. Please chime in here if this isn't normal, or anything I can do to minimise the memory usage so I can make many keystone installs get along on the same low-spec server.

Comment: we're not focusing on optimizing memory usage. But if the usage is prohibitive and you fix it we'd gladly accept a PR

Comment: @squishdish ... Can you post the code where you configure / initialize Keystone?

Answer (score 0):

"Keystone_6" requires near 800mb for "basic" start. In complex with Ubuntu-22 and other needed soft your RAM must be no less then 1500mb. Therefore you shoud rent server with 2000mb RAM minimum. Otherwise, the application simply freezes upon launch.